# Cloud Firestore whereIn not returning the data docs mentioned

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the database mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#example_data) and using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) query in Flutter as:

```dart
collection.where('regions', whereIn: [['west_coast', 'east_coast']]);
```

Docs says:

> From the example data, only the DC document qualifies with its region field of ["east_coast"]

But my query isn't returning anything. Rest of the queries are working as expected but not this one. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Try your code without `[]`. It should work

Comment: @FaridShumbar Do you mean `whereIn: ['west_coast', 'east_coast']`, I already tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: Cloud you please also share the whole query?

Comment: @FaridShumbar I'm using the query provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any).

Comment: It could be because of how you reference the collection: you are not pointing the query to any collection. It should be something like `collection("cities")` but in this case, the collection is empty

Comment: @FaridShumbar Needless to say I was actually using `collection('cities')` otherwise how come my other queries were working!

Comment: Can you add a [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your description in order to reproduce it?

Comment: @FaridShumbar Just use the data from the sample I linked earlier and run my query.